# How to split/extract a new column and remove the extracted string from the column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, extract

I have a sample dataframe

```
data = {"col1" : ["1 first 1", "2 second 2", "third 3", "4 fourth 4"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
print(df)


     col1
0   1 first 1
1   2 second 2
2     third 3
3   4 fourth 4
```

I want to extract the first `digit` in the column and remove them

I tried to extract using

```
df["index"] = df["col1"].str.extract('(\d)')
```

```
    col1       index
0   1 first 1   1
1   2 second 2  2
2   third 3     3
3   4 fourth 4  4
```

I want to remove the extracted digit from `col1` if I use `replace` both the start and end digits will be replaced.

**Desired Output**

```
    col1    index
0   first 1     1
1   second 2    2
2   third 3     NaN
3   fourth 4    4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for processing each column separately:

```
#added ^ for start of string
pat = '(^\d)'
df = df.assign(col1 = df["col1"].str.replace(pat, '', regex=True),
               index= df["col1"].str.extract(pat))
print (df)
        col1 index
0    first 1     1
1   second 2     2
2    third 3   NaN
3   fourth 4     4
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `regex` pattern **'^(\d)'** which means you want to access one digit at the start of string.

- **^** refers to the start of string.
- **\d** means one digit

```
df["index"] = df.col1.str.extract("^(\d)")
df.col1 = df.col1.str.replace('^(\d)',"",regex = True)

print(df)

      col1   index
0    first 1     1
1   second 2     2
2    third 3   NaN
3   fourth 4     4
```